# angular form disable submit button if field is empty

Tags: forms, angular

Sounds so simple but I've tried quite a few things and none work.

I'm using Angular 4 and my form is template-driven:

```
<form #form="ngForm" novalidate>
    <label for="insz">{{ 'SEARCH_PAGE.searchInszNumber' | translate }}</label>
    <input type="text" name="insz" [placeholder]="'SEARCH_PAGE.searchInszNumber' | translate" #input required>
    <button (click)="onSearch(input.value)" ><span>{{'SEARCH_PAGE.search' | translate }}</span></button>
</form>
```

I want to disable the button when the (one and only) input field is empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing `ngModel` in your input, for your input field to actually be a form control:

```html
<input type="text" name="insz" ngModel
    [placeholder]="'SEARCH_PAGE.searchInszNumber' | translate" #input required>
```

and then you need to disable the button of course if form is not valid:

```html
<button [disabled]="!form.valid" (click)="onSearch(input.value)" >Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried this before and was not working so I thought `ngModel` was not necessary. Then I just noticed the `novalidate` attribute on the form...

Comment: `novalidate` btw is not needed in angular 4 anymore, if you are using that. That is actually for disabling browser native validation.

Comment: Yes I'm using Angular 4! Thanks, didn't know that either.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). I had no knowledge of them until a week ago, but they're so powerful !

This means all you need to do is add a `Validator` (`Validators.required` in your case), and add a disabled condition to your button. And that's it, you're set.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! This is rather a simple form so I thought I should use a template-driven one, but I'll give reactive forms a try as well.

Comment: I agree, they are great, but I'd say it's overkill in this scenario, where there is just one input field :)

Comment: It's never overkill. Yes, it's a bit more difficult to use them, but you have to write less code (in this case, you only need to add the validator)